# JQuery: How to get specific object value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So I have a autocomplete function of JQuery,

```
function autocomplete(){
$('.to_msg').autocomplete({
    source: "ajax/auto_complete_ajax.php",
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        var val = ui;
        console.log(val);

    }
});
}
```

The object returned from json_encode of php result is

```
Object
  item: Object
   label: "Melde Feliciano"
   user_id : "5"
   value : "Melde Feliciano"
__proto__:Object
```

All I want is to return only the user_id which is 5 the value of user_id, how to do that? I need to get the specific value from object

Comment: `val.item.user_id`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Thanks looks like so easy